# Any way to squash last N images in buildah (or podman) without additional tools?

Tags: podman, buildah

Actually, the question title says it all.

I found two tools that can possibly solve the problem, but I'd much rather go with something built into podman/buildah that already have the know-how of dealing with layers in an image:

- https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash
- https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash

Answer (score 3):

I see two options in `podman`:

```sh
$ podman build --help | grep squash 
      --squash        squash newly built layers into a single new layer
      --squash-all    Squash all layers into a single layer

$ podman --version
podman version 3.4.0
```

I think the latter also squashes the base container layers, which is not the Docker behaviour for this command.

You can check at this [GitHub PR](https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/4215) for more info.